# Windows Form - auto increment form number from last acess table value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

I have a windows form (in VisualStudio-10) that can load/save entries to the database, navigate existing entries and edit them within the form. What I would like to do is have the form number (4 digit primary key for each entry) increment by 1 from the last entry in the Access DB table any time a new entry is created.

Is there a way to call the index of the last entry, increment it by 1 and print that number to the form number text box? I haven't been able to find a ton of helpful info in my searches thus far, so if you can point me in the right direction or towards another question it'd be much appreciated, Thanks.

This is the update function / connection to the db. The database name is **servicereq1** and the table name is **servicereq**. The text-box I would like to have the updated key displayed in is **serviceRequestNumberTextBox**. Thanks again for the help.

```
private void updateButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"\\prod\ServiceRequests");
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\servicereq1.mdb";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE servicereq SET ServiceRequestNumber = @servreq, DateLogged = @datelogged, LoggedBy = @loggedby, [Problem In Environment] = @problemfoundin, Function = @function, [Other Impacts] = @summary, Account = @earningsaccount, [From] = @from, [To] = @to, Status = @status, Description = @description, Fixer = @fixer, [Time Estimate] = @timeestimate, [Actual Start] = @actualstart, [Actual Finish] = @actualfinish, [Actual Time] = @actualtime, [Programs/Forms] = @programsforms, Comments = @comments, [Retest Date] = @requestdate, Tester = @tester, [Code In Environment] = @codein WHERE (ServiceRequestNumber = @servreq)");
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@servreq", serviceRequestNumberTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datelogged", dateLoggedTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loggedby", loggedByComboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problemfoundin", problem_In_EnvironmentComboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@function", functionTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@summary", other_ImpactsTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@earningsaccount", accountTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", fromTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", toTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", statusComboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", descriptionTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fixer", fixerComboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeestimate", time_EstimateTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actualstart", actual_StartTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actualfinish", actual_FinishTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actualtime", actual_TimeTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@programsforms", programs_FormsTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", commentsTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@requestdate", retest_DateTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tester", testerComboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codein", code_In_EnvironmentComboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@servreq", serviceRequestNumberTextBox.Text);
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Form Updated Successfully");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the save new record function.

```
    private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"\\prod\ServiceRequests");
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\servicereq1.mdb";

            String servreq = serviceRequestNumberTextBox.Text;
            String datelogged = dateLoggedTextBox.Text;
            String loggedby = loggedByComboBox.Text;
            String problemfoundin = problem_In_EnvironmentComboBox.Text;
            String function = functionTextBox.Text;
            String summary = other_ImpactsTextBox.Text;
            String earningsaccount = accountTextBox.Text;
            String from = fromTextBox.Text;
            String to = toTextBox.Text;
            String status = statusComboBox.Text;
            String description = descriptionTextBox.Text;
            String fixer = fixerComboBox.Text;
            String codein = code_In_EnvironmentComboBox.Text;
            String programsforms = programs_FormsTextBox.Text;
            String timeestimate = time_EstimateTextBox.Text;
            String actualstart = actual_StartTextBox.Text;
            String actualfinish = actual_FinishTextBox.Text;
            String actualtime = actual_TimeTextBox.Text;
            String retestdate = retest_DateTextBox.Text;
            String tester = testerComboBox.Text;
            String comments = commentsTextBox.Text;


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into servicereq ([ServiceRequestNumber], DateLogged, LoggedBy, [Problem In Environment], Function, [Other Impacts], Account, [From], [To], Status, Description, Fixer, [Code In Environment], [Programs/Forms], [Time Estimate], [Actual Start], [Actual Finish], [Actual Time], [Retest Date], Tester, Comments) Values(@servreq, @datelogged, @loggedby, @problemfoundin, @function, @summary, @earningsaccount, @from, @to, @status, @description, @fixer, @codein, @programsforms, @timeestimate, @actualstart, @actualfinish, @actualtime, @requestdate, @tester, @comments)");
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@servreq", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = servreq;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@datelogged", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = datelogged;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@loggedby", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = loggedby;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@problemfoundin", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = problemfoundin;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@function", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = function;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@summary", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = summary;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@earningsaccount", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = earningsaccount;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@from", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = from;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@to", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = to;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = status;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = description;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fixer", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fixer;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@codein", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = codein;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@programsforms", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = programsforms;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@timeestimate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeestimate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualstart", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = actualstart;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualfinish", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = actualfinish;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualtime", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = actualtime;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@requestdate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = retestdate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@tester", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tester;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@comments", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = comments;

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Form Submitted Successfully");
                    servicereqBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
            }
            this.servicereqTableAdapter1.Load(servicereq1DataSet2.servicereq, serviceRequestNumberTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an UPDATE query, you already know the `serviceRequestNumberTextBox` value because you are passing it to the WHERE clause of your sql text. Are you referring to the INSERT query?

Comment: I know the value of any current record in the DB, however when I create a new record, all text-boxes are empty. I would like for the serviceRequestNumberTextbox to be updated with the last index of the db + 1 when a user creates a new record.

Comment: This sounds like the work of an Autonumber value for the primary key of your table. I have also noticed that you store the database in a network location. There are other users that concurrently insert new records?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple users who use this form. If I were to make my primary key an autonumber, how does this address the issue of the user still needing to enter a number in the textbox. If the user leaves it blank will the table auto-fill it by virtue of it being an autonumber?

Comment: Yes, autonumber are calculated by the database engine. You don't need to know them for the INSERT and you should not try to pass them in the INSERT query. So, if you make the ServiceRequestNumber an autonumber then remove it from the INSERT (both field and value)

Comment: And consider that in case of multiuser scenario this is the only approach that could give you certainity of the number assigned.

Comment: @Steve I removed serviceRequestNumberTextBox from the DB queries and its auto incrementing just like I wanted. Please make your suggestion an answer so I can mark it for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach in a multiuser scenario like this is to change the ServiceRequestNumber field to be an AUTONUMBER field. In this way the database engine calculates the new number and you don't risk the situation in which the same number is assigned to different user working in the same database but from two different PCs.

Of course, you don't need to pass anything in the INSERT query for this field, so remove the ServerRequestNumber and its parameter placeholder from the INSERT query text.

if you want to know what is the AUTONUMBER assigned to your record you could write this sql

```
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(......))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn))
{
      conn.Open();
      int newServiceRequestNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
      ....
}
```

Notice that you should keep your connection and other disposable objects inside a using block to be sure that they are disposed and closed

Answer (score 2):

As Steve said in the comments the simplest way to do that would be to set that colunm as an autonumber in the database and simply remove the textbox for the id in the form that adds new entries. In your `INSERT` command, do not give any value for the id and the database will automaticly generate a new number (last id + 1) for that new entry.